# How to create tap devices using virsh?

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

This is a snippet from configuration file created using qemu-kvm management tool. How do I create the same config using VMM or virsh?

```
[net]
  type = "nic"

[net]
  type = "tap"
  script = "/etc/ovs-ifup"
  downscript = "/etc/ovs-ifdown"
```

Answer (score 3):

This configuration file indicates that you're using OpenVSwitch to manage virtual network ports for you KVM virtual machines.

Refer to this [article](http://git.openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=openvswitch;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL.KVM;hb=HEAD) for howtos and how it creates/destroy virtual network ports.

You can use this command to create and then enable new tap device `vnetX`:
`ip tuntap add dev vnetX mode tap`
`ip link set up dev vnetX`